# Mapping the intersection of hyperplanes/simplex to lower-dimensional unit-simplex

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, functions, systems-of-equations, geometric-topology

Suppose I have an object in $\mathbb{R}^5$ described by:

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=1$$
$$x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4+5x_5=6$$
$$x_1+7x_2+8x_3+9x_4+10x_5=11$$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5 \geq 0$$

Is there a way that I could map this object onto the k-dimensional
unit-simplex, described by (I don't really know what dimension is proper for having a bijection, but as long as it is a mapping to an unit-simplex that is fine):

$${x_1}\prime + {x_2}\prime + ... +{x_k}\prime = 1$$
$${x_1}\prime, {x_2}\prime, ..., {x_k}\prime \geq 0$$

Best case scenario, I want a mapping that is **invertible and linear**. Moreover, the inverse image of the mapping should be equal to the domain of the map.

*I am interested in this because: I want to sample from the object in $\mathbb{R}^5$, but it is difficult to do so. I can, however, sample easily from the lower-dimensional simplex. Thus, if I could have an invertible mapping with nice properties, this might solve my problem!*

Comment: I think this is not possible by dimension reasons: a bijection between linear objects is an isomorphism, and linear objects of different dimension cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: sorry, but I might have done the dimension wrong. I just want to map the object to a k-dimensional unit-simplex, whatever dimension the simplex is I don't mind! I'll make the edit to the original question now.

Comment: It would appear that the solution set of your three equations and five inequalities $x_i \geq 0$ is empty. You really ought to check that.

Comment: Wrote it out for a revised problem in which the solution set is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: turns out the region is empty. Go Figure.

the object in question is a convex pentagon in a 2-plane; The plane can be described by finding a favorite point $P$ in it in $\mathbb R^5;$ then find, say, an orthonormal basis $\vec{u}, \vec{v}$ for the plane given when all three right-hand sides are changed to $0.$ Your pentagon is then given as $$ P + s \vec{u} + t  \vec{v}, $$
with five linear inequalities on the pair $(s,t)$ in order to satisfy all the $x_i \geq 0.$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & -5 & -10 & -15 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & -1 & -2 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I get
$$ \vec{u} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 6} \left(0,1,-2,1,0 \right)  $$
$$ \vec{v} = \frac{1}{\sqrt {30}} \left(0,2,-1,-4,3 \right)  $$
which you can check yourself, easier to ignore the square roots.

Next you need the one favorite point $P,$ which amounts to repeating this whole matrix business, but augmented with the original $1,6,11$ as another column, finding row echelon form, and picking a solution with all $x_i \geq 0.$

Alright, well, did it myself, I no longer believe that the region is feasible. Indeed, I get the augmented matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & -2 & -3\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which requires, for all nonegative $x_i,$ that

$$ x_4 + 2 x_5 \geq 3, $$
$$ 2 x_4 + 3 x_5 \leq 4. $$
So, if you copied the problem correctly, they are just screwing with you.
since
$$ - x_4 - 2 x_5 \leq -3, $$
$$ -3 x_4 - 6 x_5 \leq -9, $$
$$ 4 x_4 + 6 x_5 \leq 8, $$
$$   x_4 \leq -1. $$

Alright, let me change the problem to force a solution with all entries equal to $1,$ so the new system is
$$ \color{magenta}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=5,}$$
$$  \color{magenta}{x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4+5x_5=15,}$$
$$  \color{magenta}{x_1+7x_2+8x_3+9x_4+10x_5=35,}$$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5 \geq 0.$$
As a result, we have parametrized the set as
$$ (1,1,1,1,1) + \frac{s}{\sqrt 6} \left(0,1,-2,1,0 \right)  + \frac{t}{\sqrt {30}} \left(0,2,-1,-4,3 \right)  $$
or
$$ \left(1, \;  1 + \frac{s}{\sqrt 6} + \frac{2t}{\sqrt {30}}, \;  1 - \frac{2s}{\sqrt 6} - \frac{t}{\sqrt {30}}, \;  1 + \frac{s}{\sqrt 6} - \frac{4t}{\sqrt {30}}, \;  1  + \frac{3t}{\sqrt {30}}   \right).  $$

In this case, the polygon is $st$ space is a non-empty convex set, as $(s=0,t=0)$ is in it,
$$  \color{magenta}{ 1 + \frac{s}{\sqrt 6} + \frac{2t}{\sqrt {30}} \geq 0,} $$
$$  \color{magenta}{ 1 - \frac{2s}{\sqrt 6} - \frac{t}{\sqrt {30}} \geq 0,} $$
$$  \color{magenta}{1 + \frac{s}{\sqrt 6} - \frac{4t}{\sqrt {30}} \geq 0,} $$
$$  \color{magenta}{ 1  + \frac{3t}{\sqrt {30}}  \geq 0.} $$

[image]

Comment: Hi Will! Thank you so much for this, but what about the constraint $s+t=1$. Also, just to clarify, what exactly is the mapping?

Comment: Isn't finding $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ just finding the basis for the null space of the matrix? Adding $P$ to the linear combination of the basis gives me the complete solution. But, how does that turn into a mapping onto the 3D unit-simplex? (sorry if I'm missing an obvious point here)

Comment: do you have any idea on how I could map this to a unit-simplex (I don't care 2D or 3D)?

Comment: @AndyYao it is NOT a simplex

Comment: I know it is not a simplex, but do you think there exists a bijection between this object and the simplex?

Comment: @AndyYao, nothing of any use. There is always a bijection between two convex bodies (with interior) of the same dimension. Pick a central interior point for one of them. Map to the unit disc (or ball), center to center. Next, map the boundary to the boundary by $$ x \mapsto x / |x| $$ where $x$ is the ordinary Euclidean length of the nonzero vector $x.$ Finally, for interior points other than the chosen center, map $t x $ to $t x / |x|$ for real $0 \leq t \leq 1.$ Do the same for the other convex body, one mapping composed with the inverse of the other.  What is your actual background?????????

Comment: Hi Will. Sorry for this late reply! The background is that I have a largely underdetermined matrix Ax = b (perhaps, 5 by 1000), from which I want to sample the solution space from. It is also required that the x's be non-negative element-wise. My current Monte-Carlo Markov Chain hitandrun algorithm is too slow to sample Ax=b directly, but I could sample a k-dimensional simplex very quickly. Just thinking about this, I don't need a bijection, but just an injective function whose image covers the convex body defined by Ax=b, x >= 0.

Comment: any thoughts on this approach? thanks a lot!!!